# У реки бывает пейзаж?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Это река жизни и символ Крещения. **Нам даже продемонстрирован её
>   пейзаж.** Интересно, что потом искусство займется разработкой
>   подробных сюжетов, происходящих на Иордане.

[Фредерик Базиль - Пейзаж реки Лез](http://impressionism.su/bazille/Landscape_by_the_Lez_River.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и какой же это "пейзаж реки"? Это какое-то по долинам и по взгорьям...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*По мере нашего продвижения на север, все красочнее и интереснее становился пейзаж реки.*
**[Ю. Юсупов. Удачливый рыболов](https://books.google.ee/books?id=BRalAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT139&lpg=PT139&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=y7Kj7CvGYt&sig=KuN1fmbYq8_5vQcICOHg6HcxHeY&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLl_iIkJ7ZAhVD_aQKHdZ6AEY4ChDoAQhKMAk#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false)**

*Ее пересекает плотина гидроэлектростанции имени В. И. Ленина. Красив пейзаж реки в районе Днепродзержинска.*
[**Е. Рябчиков. Дон идет к Волге**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=1-g_AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=WDlw04pFZt&sig=5hDV-wMtj2fJMGDCr3jVM0dDIjE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihx5DRkJ7ZAhVI3qQKHc_6Bec4FBDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false) (журнал "Огонёк", 1952)

*Радует глаз столичных жителей новый пейзаж реки Тэдон: по ее прозрачной воде ходят экскурсионные суда, которые работают не на топливе, а с использованием солнечной энергии.*

Answer (score 3):

"Пейзаж реки" встречается в весьма солидных контекстах. Но в данном конкретном случае я бы поостерёгся. Картина в оригинале называется "Paysage au bord du Lez" и обычно это название принято переводить на русский так: "Пейзаж на берегу Лез". Я бы предложил уточнить официальный перевод (проверить пердложенный мной вариант*) и использовать его в книге.

*К сожалению, я не смог найти надёжный источник.

Comment: Гриззлик, спасибо за отклик! Картину Фредерика Базиля я привела "от себя", в тексте речь об Иордане. Я просто не поверила в такой ***пейзаж реки***...

Answer (score 1):

"Пейзаж реки", "натюрморт фруктов" — неверно, на мой взгляд. Но надо смириться, наверно. У нас же христианская тема :))

Нашелся-таки один-единственный "пейзаж реки" в Нацкрпусе:

> В 1875–1880 годах по этюдам П. Верещагин исполнил картины, изображающие пейзажи реки Чусовой с высокими горами ― „камнями” на берегах, а также деревни, заводы и города Урала. [Алексей Иванов. Message: Чусовая. Части 6-7 (2007)]

А вот еще "пейзажи", и их немало:

> Теперь этот чудесный пейзаж долины Эльбы обезображен новой постройкой. [Александр Волков. Семь чудес такой хрупкой природы // «Знание-сила», 2012]
>
> Особенно впечатляет пейзаж ночного Сеула. Кресты на храмах в Корее принято подсвечивать, и вечером становится ясно, что корейскую столицу трудно назвать городом «сорока сороков церквей» ― их явно больше 1600. [Андрей Ланьков. Религия прогресса и развития // «Эксперт», 2013]

Comment: Пример не один, гугл отзывается на "пейзаж реки", но откликается вот такими картинами, как в подвопросье... Я думаю: это только мне не нравится? Может, вкусовщину проявляю? Но это не то же, что "натюрморт фруктов".

Comment: Надо смириться, наверно. У нас же христианская тема :))